# data mismatching if hide some column in datatables

Tags: javascript, search, datatables

I have already assigned some columns to hide from list but I am unable to hide those column's search option in datatables and php.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
              "bVisible": false,
               "aTargets" : [0,8,11,12,15]
              }
            ]
```

this is for creating the select box for searching individual column.

```
$("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
   this.innerHTML += fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
   $('select', this).change( function () {
       oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
   } );
} );
```

Now could you please tell me what to do so that the corresponding select box which is appearing top of the column for individual column search will be disappeared?
 Thanks in advance.